# Removing file name after / bypass validation

Tags: php

I pressed the login button and if there's no email save on the database it will redirect to the following url https://www.example.com/enter_here. I used `header("Location: {$_SITE['url']}/enter_here");` to redirect it. Once on that page if i remove the enter_here it will bypass that validation where it will directly login the user. Is there anyway to prevent so that even i remove the enter_here it wont go to the other page.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. There are plenty of ways, like adding some check to see if the user has logged in or not.

Comment: Hi Sir, will you let me know how and which one you think is the best?

Comment: You could read up on [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and also do some research. There are plenty of tutorials about this if you just spend some time searching for it. SO isn't a free coding service, nor the correct place to ask for tutorials.

Comment: I did try to look online but i can't find any, anyway ill do what you said.

Comment: wrap the validation work in a function then you can use this function in any page the user might request. I think you need your application to adopt some sort of 1 entry point design (e.g front controller)